# Downsample by calculating mean value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Lets say i have a file with 44100 samples, sampled at fs=44100 Hz.
So my file is 1second long.

I want to downsample this to a sample frequency of 8 Hz, but i want to do this NOT by taking every 44100/8 = 5512,5 sample and save in a new array. But by taking the mean value of the first 5512 samples, save in place 1 of new array. Then take sample 5513-11024, the mean value of this and save in place 2 of the new array. And so on... And take sample 11025 to 11025+5512 and put the mean value of this in place 3 of the array.

I know it has to be some kind of double for loop, but i just can't figure out how... Any help?

EDIT:

Code that in a very manual way does what i'm looking for.

`    fs=44100;
    fo=8;
    A = randn(44100,1); %array sampled at fs=44100 with random data

```
A_resampled = zeros(numel(A)/5512);     

first_block = zeros(5512,1);  

for i = 1:length(first_block)  
   first_block(i) = A(i);  
end  

first_mean_value = mean(first_block);  

A_resampled(1) = first_mean_value;  

second_block = zeros(5512,1);  

for k = 5513:5512+length(second_block)  
   second_block(k) = A(k);  
end  

second_mean_value = mean(second_block);  

A_resampled(2) = second_mean_value;`
```

and so on...

Comment: Single for loop is enough. give it a try and we will help once we have seen some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)? Let `x` denote your input vector. Then

```
n = ceil((1:numel(x))/5512.5); %// blocks of 5512, 5513, 5512, 5513... samples
result = accumarray(n(:), x (:), [], @mean);
```

Note that `n` automatically defines **unequal block sizes, differing by one sample at most**, to match your **fractional target block size**. In your example, block sizes are `5512`, `5513`, `5512`, `5513`...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this doesn't do what i'm after. Maybe i didn't explain my self well enough. Ill try post some code (in main post) that does what im after in a very manual way, maybe that will make it easier to understand. But thank you very much.

Comment: Jeez sorry guys, my test was wrong and both @rayryeng and Luis Mendo 
gave correct results. Going with Mendo's since it's a more correct result with the switching between 5512 and 5513 chunks.

Answer (score 2):

```
sampling = 1:5512:length(sample);
resampled = zeros(numel(sampling),1);
for ii = 1:length(sampling)-1
    resampled(ii,1) = mean(sampling(ii:ii+1));
end
```

`sampling` is an array with indices to start sampling and then a loop simply takes the mean of all those bits.

Comment: You know what Divakar would say about your using loops, rigtht? :-P But the OP asked for that, so +1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this doesn't do what i'm after. Maybe i didn't explain my self well enough. Ill try post some code (in main post) that does what im after in a very manual way, maybe that will make it easier to understand. But thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

[`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) the array into a 2D matrix, then find the [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) along the columns.  Just to make sure we can do this properly, we're going to pad the end of the array so that we're sure that your signal is an integer multiple of `fs/fo` where `fs` is the sampling frequency and `fo` is the desired frequency... so this would be `44.1 kHz` and `8 Hz` respectively.

As such, assuming your signal is stored in `A`, do this:

```
%// Defines
A = ....; %// Define your array here
fs = 44100; %// Sampling frequency
fo = 8; %// Desired frequency

%// Determine how many samples there are per chunk
samples_per_chunk = floor(fs/fo);

%// Determine how many total chunks there are
num_chunks = ceil(numel(A)/samples_per_chunk);

%// Create a padded array where it is an integer multiple
%// of the chunk size and insert the original array into this padded
%// array
Apad = zeros(samples_per_chunk*num_chunks,1);
Apad(1:numel(A)) = A;

%// Reshape into 2D matrix
M = reshape(Apad, [], num_chunks);

%// Find average per chunk
out = mean(M, 1);
```

---

However, a consequence with this is that should your array not be an integer multiple of `fs/fo`, you will be unnecessarily averaging a bunch of zeroes that get appended to the end of the array.  If you don't want this to happen, one way would be to create a matrix initially padded with `NaN` and to use [`nanmean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) instead so that none of the values that are `NaN` are included in the average... thus effectively ignoring the padded values.

Something like this would work instead:

```
%// Code as before..
%// ...
%// ...

%// New
Apad = nan(samples_per_chunk*num_chunks,1);
Apad(1:numel(A)) = A;

M = reshape(Apad, [], num_chunks);
out = nanmean(M, 1);
```

However, `nanmean` requires the Statistics Toolbox.  If you don't have this, then you can implement `nanmean` yourself.  After you reshape the array to the matrix `M`, count how many `NaN` elements there are per column and calculate the average yourself by summing all of the columns and dividing by the total number of entries that aren't `NaN`.

```
%// Code as before...
%//....
%//....

%// New
M = reshape(Apad, [], num_chunks);

%// Count how total number of NaN values
counts = sum(isnan(M), 1);

%// Set NaN values to zero to not affect mean
M(isnan(M)) = 0;

%// Calculate new average
out = sum(M,2) ./ (size(M,1) - counts);
```

Comment: @LuisMendo - Thanks :) Note the explicit use of the `1` in `mean` ;)

Comment: Oooh... I hadn't noticed that. Could you add a `.'` somewhere just to make it prettier? :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo - :D... I could transpose `M` and use `2` for the mean ;)

Comment: i dont really 100% understand the code, but i get the correct result for the first mean value of the first 5512 samples. Then the second value in the array that should be the mean value of the next 5512 samples in the array gets wrong. At least if i calculated it correctly manual. See code update in main post.

Comment: @ELEFAAANT - That doesn't make sense.  Hand calculations that I did show that this code is correct.  Either you aren't describing what you want properly, or you aren't calculating what you want correctly on your end.  Please update your post.

Comment: I tried updating my post, sorry it took some time. Hope i explained it well enough.